# Like query in mongodb to match any wording out of the name in PHP

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I am working on a app where i am implementing the web api in flight framework. I am using mongodb database & want to do "Like" query in the database to retrieve records where the restaurant name matching the given words anywhere in its name.

I am doing this with following way :

```
    $mongoDb = MongoDbConnector::getCollection('restaurants');
        $regex = new MongoRegex('/\b' . $restaurantName . '\b/i');
            $restaurantListDataCount = $mongoDb->find(array('city' => $city, 'name' => $regex))->count();
```

thing is i am getting count as 0 here even though more than 100 records having the particular string i am searching for exists in its name.

How the regex be in a way modified to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just Change like that

```
  $regex = new MongoRegex('/.*' . $restaurantName . '.*/i');
```

Comment: Exactly what i want. Thanks